# Current UTC date string with to_iso_extended_string in millisecond format

Tags: c++, boost

I want to generate the current UTC date time in milliseconds precision but I am only be able to get it in seconds or microsec precision.
Is it possible to get it in milliseconds precision?

```
std::cout << to_iso_extended_string(microsec_clock::universal_time()) + "Z" << std::endl;

"2020-02-27T13:05:46.543801Z"

std::cout << to_iso_extended_string(second_clock::universal_time()) + "Z" << std::endl;

"2020-02-27T13:11:00Z"
```

Expected format:

```
"2020-02-27T13:05:46.543Z"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can take a substring from the microsecond version.

Something like:

```
std::string microsec_time = to_iso_extended_string(microsec_clock::universal_time());

std::string millisec_time = microsec_time.substr(0, microsec_time.size()-3);

std::cout << millisec_time << 'Z' << std::endl;
```

It should give you the output you expect.